# read_delim of literal data after modifications to huge character vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I have a number of pipe-delimited files, a few very large (many GB), that are flawed. Someone mistakenly left out one field and a delimiter, but only in some of the rows.

I'd like to read each file as a vector of character strings using `read_lines`, then apply `count.fields` (is there a tidyverse version of this?) to split the lines into two vectors of strings by the number of tokens. (I must delete the last string in one of the vectors).  After all that manipulation, I want to use `read_delim` twice to parse the sets of lines with a different number of delimiters.  How can I fool `read_delim` to read each vector of strings without any modifications?  Or is my only solution to write new temporary files and then use `read_delim`?

The online help for `read_delim` says:  "file" can be a literal but "It must contain at least one new line to be recognised as data (instead of a path)."

"paste" can add newlines (like shown below), but why should I need to do this to fool `read_delim` into reading the literal data instead of a path?  Why not add a parameter to `read_delim` so it an read literal data in the form a vector of strings?

I want to pass the targetSet string vector, but `read_delim` needs a newline:

```
 d <- read_delim(paste(targetSet, collapse="\n"), delim="|",
                  col_types=cols(.default="c"))
```

This works on files that have 100,000 records, but paste fails with one file of about 160 million records:

> Error in paste(targetSet, collapse = "\n") :   result would exceed
>   2^31-1 bytes

I'm using 64-bit R, so I don't understand this message.  I should have dozens of GB of memory on the Linux box I'm using.

Is there a trick to get `read_delim` to read a modified vector of strings from read_lines?  Is there a tidyverse version of `textConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the `paste` source code in `paste.c`, we find the two lines

> if (pwidth > INT_MAX)
>      error(_("result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes"));

So `paste` checks if the length of the pasted character string is `<= INT_MAX`, and returns above error if it is not.

R has a `LONG_INT_MAX` and an `INT_MAX`, the latter of which is a 32bit integer therefore can have a maximum value of `2^31 - 1` (one bit for the sign), corresponding to around 2.1 billion.

It seems that `paste(targetSet, collapse = "\n")` exceeds that character limit.